# FluentValidation - SetAsyncValidator for RuleForEach

Tags: c#, asynchronous, fluentvalidation

i'm a problem with the SetAsyncValidator inside a RuleForeach to validate a collection. I need the async Validator because i need to check if the record already exist.

I use a Mediatr validation's pipeline in async mode.

Surfing the net I haven't found similars scenario. How can i realize that ?
**Product Category class**

```
public class ProductCategory : AuditableEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private List<ProductSubCategory> _productSubCategories;

    //public IEnumerable<ProductSubCategory> ProductSubCategories => _productSubCategories.AsReadOnly();
    public List<ProductSubCategory> ProductSubCategories => _productSubCategories;
    public ProductCategory()
    {
        _productSubCategories = new List<ProductSubCategory>();
    }

    public void AddProductSubcategory(string name)
    {
        var productSubCategory = new ProductSubCategory(name);
        _productSubCategories.Add(productSubCategory);
    }
}

public class ProductSubCategory : AuditableEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ProductSubCategory(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public ProductSubCategory()
    {
    }
}
```

This is the synchronous rule and work very well but i would like to run asynchronously

```
When(x => x.ProductSubCategories.Any(), () =>
{
    RuleForEach(x => x.ProductSubCategories).SetValidator(new CreateProductSubCategoryCommandValidator(_repositorySub));
});
```

Validation Pipeline: Handle method

```
        public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var typeName = request.GetGenericTypeName();

        _logger.LogDebug("----- Validating command {CommandType}", typeName);

        if (!_validators.Any()) 
            return await next();
        
        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(_validators
            .Select(v => v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));
        
        var failures = validationResults.SelectMany(r => r.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Count == 0) 
            return await next();
        
        _logger.LogDebug("----- Validating command {typeName} with failures {@failures}", typeName, failures );
        throw new ValidationException(failures);
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code in your Mediatr pipeline where you are validating data? Be sure to call `ValidateAsync(...)` instead of `Validate(...)`.